# Type SampleTransaction is not defined

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

I have been following the example as shown in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

After editing the .cto, .js and .acl file , I am getting an error while I am trying to create the .bna file.

> Type SampleTransaction is not defined in namespace org.example.mynetwork

I am not understanding why this error shows up. 
I am using composer v 0.19.18.

I tried clearing all my prior installation and did a complete new installation. 
This is what I followed while installing the required stuff:

> npm install --unsafe-perm --verbose -g composer-cli@0.19
>
> npm install --unsafe-perm --verbose -g composer-rest-server@0.19
>
> npm install --unsafe-perm --verbose -g generator-hyperledger-composer@0.19
>
> npm install --unsafe-perm --verbose -g yo

What am I doing wrong?
I have added the screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGAYJ.jpg)

And Also

sssaha@EN4096144:~/fabric-dev-servers/tutorial-network$ composer archive create -t dir -n .
Creating Business Network Archive

Looking for package.json of Business Network Definition
        Input directory: /home/sssaha/fabric-dev-servers/tutorial-network
TypeNotFoundException: Type SampleTransaction is not defined in namespace org.example.mynetwork
Command failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While following the same tutorial, i made the same mistake as you did and hence had the same error: There are 2 `.js` files (in the `lib` and the `test` folders). The tutorial does not exactly say which one of the 2 we should overwrite. 
I initially overwrote the one in the `test` folder and had the same error as you since the `SampleTransaction` was still available in the `logic.js` in the `lib` folder.

If you overwrite the correct `.js` file the error will disappear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello 
This was a great help Anthony. I followed your suggestion and got the stuff done correctly this time. 
By the way, do you recommend any link or resource to understand the process that is happening when i create a network admin card or the consecutive steps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some steps, is you following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) tutorial, then **`SampleTransaction`** should not be present in any of the files (.cto, .js and .acl).

There is only one transaction in above tutorial, which is **Trade**.

Check that if **`SampleTransaction`** is present in any of these files(.cto, .js and .acl)
, just remove it.